# Can I get the Network Adapter type (wired / wireless) from its MAC address?

Tags: networking, mac-address, wifi

I know I can get the card manufacturer ID from the MAC address, what about the "type" ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard, the first three octets are the vendor id (you already know that :)) and the vendor is free to choose the last ones as they please (but they should be unique)

Therefore, even if some vendors do use a certain octet to flag wireless devices (which most likely they don't) you shouldn't rely on that as vendors are under no obligation to respect that convention.

Answer (score 1):

Short and clear answer: No.

Comment: The -1 seems a little harsh considering i answered your question ("no, but vendors may have their own vendor-specific schemes for recognising such things") as well as a bunch of info for any other people wondering the same thing - but i've edited as to your wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Most vendors have a habit of using a specific sequence per device family (following the vendor id), and sometimes even use the latter part of the serial number as the rest of the MAC.

That said, if you know the MAC of a wireless device, chances are, a device with the same first five to six octets would probably be the same kind of device.